# Thread.wait() when it enters in a method

Tags: java, concurrency

Is is correct doing this

```
owner=Thread.currentThread();
owner.wait();
```

if I want to make a thread wait when it calls the function?

I've tried to to something like this:

```
private Thread owner;
public void join() {
    Thread thread= new Thread(()-> {
        try {
            owner= Thread.currentThread();
            owner.wait();               
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

and then to wake up the thread

```
public void wakeUp() {          
        notifyAll();
}
```

NEW VERSION: waiting until I reach 5 wait ()

```
private Object mutex = new Object();
private volatile int counter;
private boolean condition=false;

public void enter() {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        counter++;
        while (!condition) {
            try {
                mutex.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
        exit();
    }
}
public void exit() {
    System.out.println("exit()");
 }

public void checkK() {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        if(counter>=5) {
            mutex.notifyAll();
            counter=0;
            condition=true;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Use a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html instead. There are several pitfalls with wait. You need to own the synchronization lock and the object you are waiting on should be private so that it cannot be signaled by accident and... easier just to use a higher-level class that works!

Comment: Ok but i can't use that, I have to implement it...

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)): “*It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances*”

Comment: ye but I have to do it, so I would like an answer ahah

Comment: No, I cannot believe that your instructions tell you specifically to call the wait, notify or notifyAll methods on a Thread instance.  Please show those instructions to us.

Comment: FYI: This tutorial will tell you everything you need to know about using `wait()`, `notify()`, and `notifyAll()`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: mmmh my trace says: "Whenever Join() is called, the caller blocks " the caller if im using the concurrency is ofc the thread no? so i thought that I have to do wait() on the thread, i'm I wrong?

Comment: Ok so for example, after 5 threads calling the join() method I have to wake up them all. Could you please check the new version of the code? Now I'm gonna to edit it

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have not yet read [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

**TLDR:** There is only one correct way to call `wait()`:

```java
synchronized(lock) {
    while (! condition) {
        lock.wait();
    }
    doSomethingThatRequiresConditionToBeTrue();
}
```

And, when you call notify() or notifyAll():

```java
synchronized(lock) {
    doSomethingThatMakesConditionTrue();
    lock.notifyAll();
}
```

The `condition` is some boolean expression that your program guarantees not to change except when the `lock` is locked.

This pattern guarantees

1. `doSomethingThatRequiresConditionToBeTrue()` cannot be called unless the `condition` is true. Not even if `wait()` returns prematurely.*
2. `wait()` can *not* be called if the `condition` is true.

The second point is more important than it looks. If your thread is awaiting an event that only happens one time, and if the `lock.notify()` call associated with that event happens *before* the `lock.wait()` call, then the `lock.wait()` probably will *never* return. That bug has a name: "[lost notification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Nonblocking_condition_variables)."

---

* The documentation for `o.wait()` warns that it could sometimes return even when `o` has not been notified.

Comment: I almost got it, so im my case I have to add and set a boolean var condition to false that turns true when the counter reaches 5.
Then I have to check in a second function if the value of the counter is >= 5, if yes i turn the condition true. I'll edit now the code to the final version, let me know what do you think. But now how can i override the run() in the right way?

Comment: @yveschuu, You don't need an explicit boolean variable. You can use any boolean expression such as `while (counter<5) {mutex.wait();}`. But, be sure that neither thread uses counter outside of a `synchronized (mutex) {...}` block.

Comment: Perfect, ty very much. sry but i'm kinda new to cuncurrency.

Comment: and now what do you suggest to do in the run() method?

Comment: @yveschuu, I don't understand. What `run()` method? I don't see any such method in your code example.

Comment: Because somehow I have to implement a run methodto let the thread understand what it needs to do right? but idk how could I do that

Comment: @yveschuu, Oops! My mistake! There _is_ a `run()` method in your _first_ example. I stupidly searched the text for the word, "run," but your `run()` method is in a lambda expression, and its name does not appear. So, yeah! Your first example shows one way to write the `run()` method for a thread. Why can't you just do the same for your newer example?

Comment: But by using lambda expression is for creating a single thread right, maybe I don't want to create only one but 100! Isn't better implementing a common run() for all the thread?

Comment: But idk how can I like make a thread only execute the method enter(), and another thread  only the method checkK()...
Because I would like to create a single thread that checks all the time if the counter is >= 5 by checkK() and maybe 20 threads that execute the method enter().

Comment: @yveschuu, Re, "how can I make a thread [do _X?_]" Write a `run()` method for the thread that does _X._ In your first example, you wrote a `run()` method as a lambda expression. You wrote `new Thread(() -> {...});` The `...` is the body of the `run()` method.

Comment: So basically I have to implement the run() for all the threads that execute the enter() method, and a lambda expr for the single thread that executes checkK()?

Comment: Ok I solved, I created 2 new class, both implement Runnable.
One that runs enter() and the second one runs checkK().
And then in the main I created many threads for one class that uses enter() and only 1 thread for the class that uses checkK()!
Ty for your solution btw.